# iframe cross-domain validate caller

Tags: iframe, cross-domain

I have a page on `A.com` that has an iframe whose `"src="` is on `B.com`. 
For example, `src="http://B.com/index.asp?123456"`

The query string `123456` is a client key assigned to domain `A.com`.
`index.asp` does a database lookup with the key to identify the domain.

How can I ensure that it was a page on `A.com` that made the call?

I thought about passing `location.host`, but that can be hacked.
That is, `C.com` could say: it's `B.com` by changing `location.host` to `B.com`.

(Obviously, `location.host` is determined via JavaScript.)

I can have other HTML code on `A.com` than just the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use postMessage and verify the origin on the event object., but you should never rely on any client side validation where security is a concern. Simply by adding a break point on the post message callback in any developer tool can easily circumvent this method.

Comment: I gather that postMessage is HTML5 and that it doesn't work in all browsers.  But, as you said, it can be hacked.

Comment: Here is a non HTML5 cross domain messaging framework [EaxyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp/)